# Best way of attaching bitmaps from library with a linkagename (currently trying with - getDefinitionByName(tempName) as Class)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I basically have 5 images in library, which I've given af linkage name as so:

head_image0, head_image1, head_image2 etc...

On Stage I have two containers which I will be loading my images into.
- pictureContainer1_mc
- pictureContainer2_mc

Pr default I have already loaded an image into container1.

What will happen is that, when I click menu button2, then head_image2 will load into container2 and fade up from alpha 0 -> alpha 1 - giving a transition between the two images.

After the image has alpha'ed into container2, then I run a function to swap containers, so that container1 will hold the image currently loaded and container2 will be ready to load another picture upon menu button click.

This looks like the following:

```
    //Function receiving an ID from the button click, which we can use to load the connected image
function headerFadeIn(receivedNumber:Number):void
{
    //Getting container2 rdy to tween from 0 -> 1
    pictureContainer2_mc.alpha = 0;

    //Preparing image string - linkagename
    var tempName:String = "header_image" + receivedNumber;

    //Loading the image into container 1
    var headImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
    var classDefinition:Class = getDefinitionByName(tempName) as Class;
    var img:BitmapData = new classDefinition(1,1);
    headImage.bitmapData = img;
    pictureContainer2_mc.addChild(headImage);

    //Tweening currecntly added image from 0 -> 1
    //When tween is done call function onFinishTween to swap containers  
    TweenLite.to(pictureContainer2_mc,1,{alpha:1, ease:menuEasing, onComplete:onFinishTween});

    function onFinishTween():void
    {
        //Setting currently loaded image in container 1         
        var headImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
        var classDefinition:Class = getDefinitionByName(tempName) as Class;
        var img:BitmapData = new classDefinition(1,1);
        headImage.bitmapData = img;
        pictureContainer1_mc.addChild(headImage);

        pictureContainer2_mc.alpha = 0;
    }
}
```

This works for me. **HOWEVER I'm experiencing some "lagging" issue**. When I've clicked back and forward menu buttons to change images like 15 times, then the tweening begins to "lag" and wont happen in a smooth transition.

Any calls on this?
Could I do this in a smarter way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to create images only once, and reuse them. Also, after the tween, i would remove the old image and save it for the next time you need that image. Also, when you swap the image from container 2 into container 1, don't create a new one, just move the image from one container to the other.

Something like this, code is not tested, just to give you an idea.

```
var instances:Object = {};
var currentImage:String;


  //Function receiving an ID from the button click, which we can use to load the connected image
function headerFadeIn(receivedNumber:Number):void
{
    //Getting container2 rdy to tween from 0 -> 1
    pictureContainer2_mc.alpha = 0;

    //Preparing image string - linkagename
    currentImage = "header_image" + receivedNumber;

    var headImage:Bitmap = _getImage(currentImage);

    pictureContainer2_mc.addChild(headImage);

    //Tweening currecntly added image from 0 -> 1
    //When tween is done call function onFinishTween to swap containers  
    TweenLite.to(pictureContainer2_mc,1,{alpha:1, ease:menuEasing, onComplete:onFinishTween});

    function onFinishTween():void
    {
        //Setting currently loaded image in container 1
            //cast returned DisplayObject into a Bitmap.        
        var headImage:Bitmap = pictureConainer2_mc.getChildByName(currentImage) as Bitmap;

        pictureContainer1_mc.addChild(headImage);

        pictureContainer2_mc.alpha = 0;
    }
}

function _getImage(id:String):Bitmap{
    if( instances[id] ) return instances[id];

    //Loading the image into container 1
    var headImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
    var classDefinition:Class = getDefinitionByName(tempName) as Class;
    var img:BitmapData = new classDefinition(1,1);
    headImage.bitmapData = img;

    instances[id] = headImage;

    return headImage;

}
```

Comment: Hey goliatone, thanks so much for taking the time to give your view on this! Truly appreciated. Im just going through your code to try and understand it correctly. In the _getImage function aint I supposed to have all the new Bitmap(); etc code in an else statement? So if instances[id] is already set then it will use the else and create the bitmap and add it to instances?

Comment: Im also getting an error on: var headImage:Bitmap = picture2.getChildByName(currentImage); - not entirely sure why. ERROR MSG: Implicit coercion of a value with static type flash.display:DisplayObject to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:Bitmap.

Comment: _getImage first checks to see if you have an instance with the provided id stored in the instances object. If it does it will return that, and exit right there. If does not it should create it and store it, only once.

Comment: The error is caused because getChildByName returns a DisplayObject, and we are assigning that object to a Bitmap instance. Edited the code. Just do picture2.getChildByName(currentImage) as Bitmap;

Comment: Wow that was a fast response :) Ahh it exist after return, then it makes sence... The fix elminated the error, however now im just getting a new one. Darn :/ TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.